# Salinity difference in KCl and NaCl

Tags: conductivity

If I calibrate my conductivity probe using KCl calibration solution, then test my aquarium water which is NaCl, will I get a false reading? When I use a digital refractometer calibrated to zero using distilled water and test my saltwater aquarium, it reads 35 PPT but when I use a conductivity probe calibrated using KCl 53,000 uSiemens it gives me a slightly different reading every time. Is this because I am calibrating to KCl but trying to measure NaCl?
Thanks for any clarification with this.

Answer (score 2):

$\ce{KCl}$  is used to calibrate conductometers via determining the device proportionality constant between the measured conductance and the known solution conductivity.

The relation between conductivity and molar concentration / mass concentration / salinity is for obvious reasons for different salts different.

It is possible the device has a built-in calculation of the $\ce{NaCl}$ salinity from conductivity, or a table or a formula is available.

If the conductometer is calibrated directly in $\ce{NaCl}$ salinity, then it must be calibrated by $\ce{NaCl}$ solution of the known salinity.

If other salts are present in sea water, they affect the measurement.

Note that conductivity raises with temperature due increased ion mobility. It is much more sensible then refraction index, so it's results change with temperature more then refractometric results.

Warmer water would lead to higher reported salinity due higher conductivity, unless there are made automatic or manual corrections.